# Query ignores filtering in WHERE-clause

Tags: sql-server, schema, left-join, where-clause

I get unexpected results from a query against a **Micrsoft SQL Server 2008** (10.0.1600.22 / Service Pack 2).

Could it be a bug?

I have tried to create a similar query to replicate the problem - without success. So I guess there's nothing wrong with the query itself, but something else is causing this somewhat strange behaviour.

I hope for some suggestions on what might be causing the problem.

First, take a look at this working example:

```
DROP TABLE #TempType
DROP TABLE #TempData

SELECT * INTO #TempType FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS Id, 10 AS TempDataFK, 'Do' AS Name, 'CODE1' AS Type   UNION
    SELECT 2 AS Id, 10 AS TempDataFK, 'Re' AS Name, 'CODE2' AS Type   UNION
    SELECT 3 AS Id, 20 AS TempDataFK, 'Mi' AS Name, 'CODE2' AS Type   UNION
    SELECT 5 AS Id, 10 AS TempDataFK, 'Fa' AS Name, 'CODE3' AS Type   UNION
    SELECT 6 AS Id, 20 AS TempDataFK, 'So' AS Name, 'CODE4' AS Type
) sub

SELECT * INTO #TempData FROM (
    SELECT 10 AS Id, 150 AS Number   UNION
    SELECT 20 AS Id, 150 AS Number   UNION
    SELECT 30 AS Id, 150 AS Number   UNION
    SELECT 40 AS Id, 180 AS Number
) sub

SELECT C1.Name Name1,
       C2.Name Name2,
       C3.Name Name3,
       C4.Name Name4,
       #TempData.Id,
       #TempData.Number
FROM #TempData
    LEFT JOIN #TempType C1 (NOLOCK)
        ON #TempData.Id = C1.TempDataFK 
        AND C1.Type = 'CODE1'
    LEFT JOIN #TempType C2 (NOLOCK)
        ON #TempData.Id = C2.TempDataFK 
        AND C2.Type = 'CODE2'
    LEFT JOIN #TempType C3 (NOLOCK)
        ON #TempData.Id = C3.TempDataFK 
        AND C3.Type = 'CODE3'
    LEFT JOIN #TempType C4 (NOLOCK)
        ON #TempData.Id = C4.TempDataFK 
        AND C4.Type = 'CODE4'
WHERE 1=1
    AND (#TempData.Number = 150)
    AND (C1.Name='Mi' OR C2.Name='Mi' OR C3.Name='Mi' OR C4.Name='Mi')
```

As you can see I'm LEFT JOINing the table `TempType` to `TempData` four times. Each time giving it a different alias. I then filter by a certain number (150) and want that at least one of the Names should be 'Mi'.

The result is as expected:

```
--------------------------------------------
Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4   Id   Number
NULL    Mi      NULL    So      20   150
--------------------------------------------
```

Nevertheless if I run a similar query against my clients database I get:

```
--------------------------------------------
Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4   Id   Number
Do      Re      Fa      NULL    10   150
NULL    Mi      NULL    So      20   150
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    30   150
--------------------------------------------
```

It is as if the part similar to `(C1.Name='Mi' OR C2.Name='Mi' OR C3.Name='Mi' OR C4.Name='Mi')` is not used in the filtering.

**Different query, but same structure**
On the clients database the tables are not temporary and they already contain data. The tables also have various other fields, but I'm still only left joining with one other table. So same structure as above.

**Couldn't replicate in new database**
I tried to replicate the problem by creating a new database with only the tables and fields affected - no succes in replicating the problem.

**Schemas**
Worth mentioning also is that the clients database contain several schemas. Both tables similar to TempData and TempType belongs to the same schema (not dbo). 
Also, the field similar to TempType.Type is a foreign key to another table in another schema, but as we're not joining with that I don't see that it would be relevant?

**Another peculiarity**
If I put C1.Name etc, as part of my SELECT, like this:

```
SELECT C1.Name Name1,
       C2.Name Name2,
       C3.Name Name3,
       C4.Name Name4,
       #TempData.Id,
       #TempData.Number,
       CASE WHEN (C1.Name = 'Mi' AND C1.Name IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN (C2.Name = 'Mi' AND C2.Name IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN (C3.Name = 'Mi' AND C3.Name IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       CASE WHEN (C4.Name = 'Mi' AND C4.Name IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

I get the expected result against my clients database (only one row):

```
Name1   Name2   Name3   Name4   Id   Number   (No column name)   (No column name)   (No column name)   (No column name)
NULL    Mi      NULL    So      20   150        0                  1                  0                  0
```

*Any suggestions what could be causing this?*

Comment: you're saying you're running a different query. Can you show us that query? If that query uses the same where, withouth the () could be a problem of precedence in the Or and in the AND. Also, why 1=1 in the where ?

Comment: Not saying this solves the issue, but note that `LEFT JOIN a ... WHERE a.something = something` turns that into an `INNER JOIN`. You may want to move the "filter" on C1 into the ON clause for the join instead of the filter clause for the query.

Comment: @ElVieejo I cannot show the original query (as it contains field names specific for the client), but the structure is 100% similar. Also the parenthesis. The 1=1 is just for easier debugging (to comment out eg. "AND (#TempData.Number = 150)")

Comment: well, in that case we're just guessing. I mean, you're showing us a query that works, and saying that another one (that you can't show us) not working. If you run both querys, each in their database, without the where clause, you're getting the same information ? This is for checking that you've the same data, in both

Comment: @ElVieejo Yes, I have the same data in both databases. And yes, I know it looks like guessing. I don't think there's anything wrong with the query. It's more if something else can cause this behaviour. Various schemas in one database? Some obsolete ANSI-settings? Some special table-settings, I'm not aware of etc...? Pasting the original query won't help. It's exactly the same. I just renamed table- and field names.

Comment: have you any proccess runinng in both databases when you're querying, that could modify the data?

Comment: Can you post the definitions of both tables including indexes? Also check these for corruption. If none found please post the execution plan. I'm suspicious of the `NOLOCK` in that it seems to be possible that data altering during the query might cause this though I haven't been able to get a repro of this myself yet.

Comment: @Martin Maybe you're right about something with the indexes is corrupt. If I cast the check on `#TempData.Number` to a varchar it works! So, changing `(#TempData.Number = 150)` to `(CAST(#TempData.Number AS varchar(5)) = '150')` makes it work! Of course that not the solution, might maybe it's a step closer to finding out what is causing the problem!

Comment: @LeifThomsen - Try running `DBCC CHECKTABLE` if that doesn't show any issues please post the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the same settings for `ansi_null` for both your local DB settings and your clients. style like "name is not null" will return the desired result, not like "name =/<> null" that depends on ansi_null settings.

check for ansi_null: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048(v=sql.105).aspx